# sql server 2012 Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a result from this query for getting top 10 values from Tags Table in which most 
Article posted

```
select distinct top 10  Name as 'Tag Name' 
from Articles join Tags on Articles.TagID=Tags.ID 
group by Tags.Name 
order by count(Articles.TagID)
```

but it's giving the following error

```
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `distinct` if you group by that column.

```
select top 10 
       Name as 'Tag Name' 
from Articles 
join Tags on Articles.TagID = Tags.ID 
group by Tags.Name 
order by count(Articles.TagID) desc
```